# Scrape webpage after saving cookies of loging in

Tags: c#, cookies

this is my code to scrape the webpage.
I got the cookies for a c# webpage control after signing in
I used them in httprequest
the response make a redirection for the webpage
I want the app to see the page using cookies to still sign in
I am scraping upwork website .. I want to get the text of the posts with specific search criterion

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)";
        if (request.CookieContainer == null)
        {
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        }


        CookieContainer c = new CookieContainer();
        string[] array = cookies.Split(new char[]
                    {
                        ';'
                    });
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            string cookie = array[i];
            string name = cookie.Split(new char[]
                        {
                            '='
                        })[0];
            string value = cookie.Substring(name.Length + 1);
            string path = "/";
            string domain = "upwork.com";
            c.Add(new Cookie(name.Trim(), value.Trim(), path, domain));
        }


        request.CookieContainer = c;

        request.Accept = "*/*";

        request.Method = "GET";

        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            }
            else
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            }

            result = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();

        }

        return result;
```

Comment: Consider using http://html-agility-pack.net/

Comment: nothing helps :/